# Publish to Azur fails with 500 internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, publish, azure-sdk-.net

I have a cloud service on Windows Azure,  I created a Asp.net WebAPI project and published to the cloud service, that was working fine from Visual Studio to publish before i updated visual studio to update 4 and azure SDK 2.2 to 2.6. But after updating when I publish, I got the following error messages. I tried several times, all failed. Can anyone help me?

even i am not able to publish a new created project on new azure service !

> 11:00:31 PM - Warning: There are package validation warnings.
>
> 11:00:31 PM - Checking for Remote Desktop certificate...
>
> 11:00:39 PM - Preparing deployment for TempAzure - 2/12/2014 10:58:23
>   PM with Subscription ID 'e94e9aeb-7003-4eae-be92-7b7ac0a1ba2c' using
>   Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
>
> 11:00:39 PM - Connecting...
>
> 11:00:39 PM - Verifying storage account 'jasontest'...
>
> 11:00:41 PM - Uploading Package...
>
> 11:06:48 PM - Warning: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.
>
> 11:11:50 PM - Warning: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.
>
> 11:26:16 PM - Warning: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.
>
> 12:00:27 AM - Warning: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.
>
> 12:05:05 AM - Warning: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.
>
> 12:27:54 AM - Unable to write data to the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Nevermind, just seen you are publishing to cloud service and not web app.  Any reason you choose a cloud service over web app for your API?  You can RDP into your cloud service and check the logs to see if something is wrong.  You can also delete your cloud service and create a new one which will rebuild your VM (incase of an issue with the VM).

Comment: Looks like the error is with uploading the .CSPKG to storage.  Can you manually create the CSPKG (select Package instead of Publish in VS) and then try to manually upload the CSPKG to storage?  If that works you can then publish from the portal.  You might also want to run Fiddler while you try to publish to see if you get any more details about the storage failure.

Comment: I did manual package and uploaded to portal. it is working fine. but the problem is VS deployment is not working.

Comment: @ Jacob Roberts : I created a new test project and created a new web service still i am getting same error for that also !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was my network connection.

to identify this problem i created VM on azure with same windows 8.1 OS and same VS. i tried to deploy from there. deployment worked fine. latter I disconnected all other devices from my internet connection and i tried to publish from my machine. it worked !

so conclusion is slow internet connection or may be now we have less timeout time for publish from VS !

Answer (score 2):

After updating from Azure SDK2.5 to SDK 2.6, I had the same problem when trying publish to my Azure service from VS2013: **Any deployment effort using Visual Studio fails after some minutes with 500 Internal server error.**

As I found the reason is the **very slow upload of the Azure package to the cloud - sometimes only between 30kB/s and 50kB/s**. The deployment fails because of an timeout which also explains, that the Azure instance logs show no sign of any deployment...

**Work around: Deploy from Azure storage**

1: Package the Azure solution, either via VisualStudio or via command line:

> MSBuild /t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=Cloud /P:Configuration=Release

2: Create an Azure storage container to upload your package to.

Continue using AzurePowerShell cmdlets:

3: Login

> Add-AzureAccount

4: Upload the package to the your Azure storage container

> $Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "yourstoragename" -StorageAccountKey "yourkey"
>
> Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "...\app.publish\yourservice.cspkg" -Container "yourazurestoragecontainer" -Blob "yourservice.cspkg" -Context $Ctx -Force

Determine the PackageURL of the uploaded package.

5: Deploy the cloud service referring to the package just uploaded to Azure cloud storage.

> Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot "Staging" -Package "PackageURL" -Configuration "PathToYourCloudConfiguration.cscfg" -label "SomeDeploymentInfo" -ServiceName "yourservicename" -Force

(Of course the entire process is scriptable. Kemp Brown wrote a great article: with a script you could adapt to explictly upload the package:
[Continuous Delivery for Cloud Services in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/))