# How do i publish a website with visual studio. It runs on local host fine but I keep getting a HTTP error 500

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

After publishing my website, it displays the home page perfectly. However, when it shows me a HTTP error 500 when I try to log in.

I have already tried to connect my database to azure and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can enable logs in azure portal to find the detailed error message. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#a-namedownloada-how-to-download-logs

Comment: 500 internal server error is generic issue. You may need to check full error message on the server. Please enable the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refer this link it may provide you the information on How to deploy a Web app using Visual Studio:

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

Error 500 is Just a generic way of saying some request are not getting proper response on time.

Also i would request you refer the post which may provide you some insight on the issue:
Reference:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518365/how-to-get-error-details-of-an-asp-net-5-app-deployed-on-azure-websites

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184344/windows-azure-publish-fails-500-internal-server-error

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/troubleshooting

Hope it helps.